# R: Using STRSPLIT and GREP on vector elements on large dataset takes too long

Tags: r, etl, strsplit

*(My first StackFlow question)*

My goal is to improve the ETL process for identifying which NetApp file shares are related to which AD permission distribution groups. Currently an application named 'TreeSize' scans a number of volumes and outputs a number of large .CSV files (35mb+). I want to merge this data and remove all permission information where each group (or named user) doesn't start with a capital G or D ('^[GD]'). With over 700,000 rows to process, it's currently taking me over 24hr to run. I hope there is a better way to process this data more efficiently to drastically cut that time down.

Here is test data which resembles actual data once all files have been merged. Use *rownum* to adjust size of data. (Real data 700000+)

**Test Data**

```
set.seed(42)
rownum <- 2000  #Real number over 700000
i <- 1
datalist <- list()

while (i <= rownum) {
  
  randomStr1 <- paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS[4:7], "-"),10, replace=TRUE),collapse="")
  randomStr2 <- paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS[4:7], " "),10, replace=TRUE),collapse="")
  randomStr3 <- paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS[4:7], " & "),10, replace=TRUE),collapse="")
  randomStr4 <- sample(c("full", "+r+w+x", "+r+x"),3)
  
  datalist$volume[i] <- rep(sample(LETTERS[1:6]))[1]
  datalist$permissions[i] <- paste(c(randomStr1,randomStr2,randomStr3),randomStr4,sep = ': ',collapse = ' | ')
  
  i = i+1
}
dat <- data.frame(datalist)
View(dat)
```

I have create a WHILE loop that cycles through my merged data. I first use STRSPLIT to create a vector containing each vector element between “ | “ each pipe. Then I pass each vector element in a GREP command searching for a RegExp of (‘^[GD]’). If found it keeps the vector element and if more than one was found it will collapse the data back together between a semicolon and space (“; “)

**Here is my current way of doing this.**

```
  i <- 1
while (i <= length(dat$permissions)) {
  df <- strsplit(dat$permissions, " \\| |: ")[[i]]              #create a vector containing each vector element      
  dat$permissions[i] <- paste(df[grep('^[GD]', df)], collapse = "; ") #Only keep where starts with G or D then Paste together
  print(paste(i, " of ", length(dat$permissions), " ", dat$permissions[i]))
i = i + 1 }
View(dat)
```

After complete,  I export to one .CSV file to complete my Transformation.

**What would be a better way to process this data to drastically reduce the time it takes to process?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to speed things up is to avoid splitting the string and to extract the matches directly using `stringr::str_extract_all()`:

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

map_chr(str_extract_all(dat$permissions, "(?<=^|\\| )[GD].*?(?=:)"), str_c, collapse =  "; ")
```

This offers a further improvement on thelatemail's already fast alternative:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  extract = map_chr(str_extract_all(dat$permissions, "(?<=^|\\| )[GD].*?(?=:)"), str_c, collapse =  "; "),
  splitmatch = sapply(strsplit(dat$permissions, " \\| |: "), \(x) paste(x[grepl("^[GD]", x)], collapse = "; ")),
  check = "equal"
)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq     max neval
    extract  5.8841  6.14375  6.681234  6.3134  6.41655 15.1264   100
 splitmatch 23.6010 24.00005 25.501808 24.2499 24.78320 40.4140   100
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the key to speeding this up is to avoid looping over each row, when it can be done in a single vectorised operation for the `strsplit` and final `paste` operations.

```
paste(
  seq_along(dat$permissions), "of", nrow(dat), 
  lapply(strsplit(dat$permissions, " \\| |: "), 
         \(x) paste(x[grepl("^[GD]", x)], collapse="; "))
)
```

Should result in a ~250 times speedup:

```
system.time({
paste(
  seq_along(dat$permissions), "of", nrow(dat), 
  lapply(strsplit(dat$permissions, " \\| |: "), \(x) paste(x[grepl("^[GD]", x)], collapse="; "))
)
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.03    0.00    0.03 

system.time({
  i <- 1
while (i <= length(dat$permissions)) {
  df <- strsplit(dat$permissions, " \\| |: ")[[i]]              #create a vector containing each vector element      
  dat$permissions[i] <- paste(df[grep('^[GD]', df)], collapse = "; ") #Only keep where starts with G or D then Paste together
  print(paste(i, " of ", length(dat$permissions), " ", dat$permissions[i]))
i = i + 1 }
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   8.11    0.06    8.17
```